# sharepoint get list fields including dropdown options

Tags: sharepoint-online, api

I am trying to get the dropdown fields within a sharepoint list via the _api. See Image below:

[image]

```
https://one365dev1.sharepoint.com/sites/nieuwsportaal/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Nieuwsberichten')/items?$select=Hoofdcategorie&$expand=FieldValuesAsText
```

I used the api endpoint above but then I realized that I am getting the items and thus not all values of "Hoofdcategorie". I am clueless however if there is any other way to get the items of the dropdown list of a field?

any help is much appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

The endpoint you need to hit is as below:

```
https://one365dev1.sharepoint.com/sites/nieuwsportaal/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Nieuwsberichten')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Hoofdcategorie'
```

In the json, the values would be retrieved somewhat as :

```
data.d.results[0].Hoofdcategorie.results
```

Generic endpoint:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Choice Field Name'
```

In the json, the values can be retrieved as :

```
data.d.results[0].Choices.results
```

where choices = internal name of the choice column

**Option 2**

There is also another way to get choice fields as below. It relies on the field display name:

```
https://one365dev1.sharepoint.com/sites/nieuwsportaal/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Nieuwsberichten')/fields/getbytitle('Hoofdcategorie')
```

Reference - [Get Fields by title](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/office/dn600182.aspx#bk_FieldCollectionGetByTitle)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
https://one365dev1.sharepoint.com/sites/nieuwsportaal/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Choice Field Name'
```